# Key-pair generation for Kadena

Tags: cardano, pact-lang, kadena

[Chainweaver](https://chainweaver.kadena.network/) uses the following code to generate a key-pair from a Bip 39-generated seed: https://github.com/kadena-io/cardano-crypto.js/blob/c50fb8c2fcd4e8d396506fb0c07de9d658aa1bae/kadena-crypto.js#L336

Is there any documentation regarding this algorithm, specifically about the reasons for the 1000X loop and about not following a BIP 44 or similar HD wallet derivation?

```
  for (let i = 1; result === undefined && i <= 1000; i++) {
    try {
      const digest = crypto.hmac_sha512(seed, [Buffer.from(`Root Seed Chain ${i}`, 'ascii')])
      const tempSeed = digest.slice(0, 32)
      const chainCode = digest.slice(32, 64)

      result = trySeedChainCodeToKeypairV1(pwd, tempSeed, chainCode)
...
```

It also looks like this is a fork of Cardano code, so is there any reason Cardano was used as inspiration for Kadena as opposed to some other coin/chain? I would really like some historical context to why some of these decisions were made.

Answer (score 1):

BIP-44 is designed for P2PKH, not ED25519.  At the time the cardano-crypto library seemed like the best available option.